# Javascript-форма

Tags: html, javascript

Форма выбора состоит из выбора оператора и суммы. К примеру

```
СТРАНА: НОМЕР: ID:

Россия  8503    1
        3353    2

Украина 2855    1   
        3855    2
```

Есть выпадающий список, и радиобутон, как можно сделать чтобы при выборе страны и радио бутанном id выводился 1 или 2 номер?

```
<select id="country_id" name="country" onchange="show_country()">
<option value="1">Россия</option>
<option value="2">Украина</option>
</select>
<input name="tariff" type="radio" onSelect="" value="" checked /> 
<input name="tariff2" type="radio" onSelect="" value="" /> 
    function show_country() 
    {
    var countryId = ge('country_id').value;
            var short_number_one = ["","8503","2855"];
            var short_number_one = ["","3353","3855"];
        ge('number').innerHTML = short_number[countryId];                               
    }   
Т
```

Comment: Не знаю, правильно я понял вопроса, но предложу такой вариант: радиокнопки, ты можешь вставить прям в <option>, а потом, с помощью jQuery добавлять элементы необходимые тебе. В этом деле, хорошая помощь jquery-docs.ru

Comment: Я думаю сделать если первая кнопка, то первый массив если вторая кнопка то второй массив, но как в JS эти кнопки получить нужно глянуть...

Comment: Давай я покажу тебе одну интересную идейку http://www.kashurin.tmweb.ru/?L=78 смысл в том, что ты можешь сделать пару таких списков, обрати внимание на структуру, вверху, ты можешь свободно в input type="hidden" сохранять промежуточные результаты, для вывода следующих меню и так далее. Возможно пригодится.

Comment: как обработать событие с радиобуттон?

Comment: обработал как OnClick спасибо всем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как онклик обрабатывать события с инпута плохой тон. И это, мягко говоря, может привести в дальнейшим к очень жутким ошибкам. Советую Вам одновременно ставить на onChange и onInput

На jQuery это выглядет следующим образом:

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('change input', function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) { // Возвращает boolean
        // Ваш код
    }
});
```

На нативном чуть больше кода, но суть та же

```
var radioEls = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');

for (var i = 0, ii = radioEls.length; i < ii; ++i) {
    radioEls[i].addEventListener('change', onChangeRadioBtn, false);
    radioEls[i].addEventListener('input', onChangeRadioBtn, false);
}

function onChangeRadioBtn(evt) {
    if (this.checked) {
        // Ваш код здесь
    }
}
```

Хотя по хорошему здесь еще нужно будет реализовать кроссбраузерный addEventListener если поддерживаются старые браузеры